# Getting the inner-most row in the embedded tables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with nested tables.And the problem is that in mouse event listener, I would like to grab the deepest row. I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18874829/how-do-i-highlight-only-the-innermost-table-row-of-a-nested-table) which is almost what I am looking for, but I am not experienced enough to use this example to solve my issue. The key to success is making alert box to display "2" instead of "1" in the below given [JSFIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7bxaraoe/)

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr id='1'><td>A
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <td><tr id='2'>B</tr></td>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

NOTE: For simplicity, I presented two levels, but would like to ask you consider the general case when any level of embedded structures might be possible.

UPDATE: See the [updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9q7g3wxf/) corrected for NewToJS's comment

Comment: You have your `td` and `tr` in the wrong place... `<td><tr id='2'>B</tr></td>` Should be `<tr id='2'><td>B</td></tr>` This will trigger the alert for the first TD since the mouse event is still hovering over the first table to get to the second table.

Comment: Why you doesn't use `:last` selector `$("tr:last")`? Check https://jsfiddle.net/k5Lko28r/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use [**`event.stopPropagation()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)
- Also note that `td` is child of `tr`, not vice versa

> `Event.stopPropagation()` Prevents further propagation of the current event in the capturing and bubbling phases.

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on('mouseover', 'tr', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log(this.id);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr id='1'>
      <td>A
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr id='2'>
              <td>B</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id='3'>
              <td>C</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Rayon, your solution works perfect for the case of two-fold structure. As I mentioned in the question, I am looking for the general case solution

Comment: @EdgarNavasardyan — These are the things one suppose to mention in the question.. Use case you have is quiet different hence specification has to be accurate.. Whether you want last tables first row ID or last tables last row ID and so on..

Comment: Rayon, edit your answer for this `var elem = $(this).find('tr:hover').length ? $(this).find('tr:hover:last') : $(this);` and I will most probably tick it as solution

Comment: @EdgarNavasardyan Is [__this__](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/oev0Lc6g/1/) what you want ?

Comment: Wow! Post this as answer

Comment: Please see my new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39936631/removing-mouseover-event-issue-in-case-of-embedded-tables