# Removing mouseover event issue in case of embedded tables

Tags: javascript, jquery

Best described as example in this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/by1r7250/)
My goal is to show the crosses when the user hovers above the tables. The problem is that the mouse-over event behavior is very strange, and it is fired for all of the children. This is the follow-on to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39936135/getting-the-inner-most-row-in-the-embedded-tables), and here I tried to be more specific about the case.

Any ideas ?

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('mouseover', 'table tbody tr', function (e) {  change_editor_icon_visibility($(this), true)});
    $(document).on('mouseout', 'table tbody tr', function (e) {  change_editor_icon_visibility($(this), false)});
});


function change_editor_icon_visibility(row_obj, mode)
{
    var elem = row_obj.find('tr:hover').length ?       
    row_obj.find('tr:hover:last') : row_obj;
        elem.find('td span.zeon-edit-pencil').toggle(mode);
}
```

Comment: What is `.remove('hover');` ?

Comment: Its your **HTML**, which is absolutely messed up.

Comment: ^ that, it's valid HTML, but why not stop nesting tables, and the issue solves itself.

Comment: Disregard `remove('hover')`. I forgot to remove that line. As for the need to use embedded tables, I am implementing an interface with lots of number crunching. And nested tables provide a neat look resembling collapsible treeview

Comment: What is wrong with HTML ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `:first` pseudo selector

> *[**`:first Selector`**](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) Selects the first matched DOM element.*

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on('mouseover', 'tr', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    change_editor_icon_visibility($(this), true)
  });
  $(document).on('mouseout', 'tr', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    change_editor_icon_visibility($(this), false)
  });
});


function change_editor_icon_visibility(row_obj, mode) {
  row_obj.find('td span.zeon-edit-pencil:first').toggle(mode);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
  .zeon-remove-sign {
    display: none;
  }
</style>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr id='1'>
      <td><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove zeon-edit-pencil zeon-remove-sign'></span>AAAAAAA
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr id='2'>
              <td>
                <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove zeon-edit-pencil zeon-remove-sign'></span>
              </td>
              <td>BBBBBBBBBBB</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id='3'>
              <td>
                <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove zeon-edit-pencil zeon-remove-sign'></span>
              </td>
              <td>CCCCCCCCCCC</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```